# How to create a process which kills it's parent and making some actions after that

Tags: linux, windows, process, operating-system

I need to implement auto-update for an application. So I decided to implement a process which checks fresh code, download it, kill the current app running, substitute the code and run it again. But when I stop the app from this child process this kills that child process as well. How could I avoid this and make it still running fine even after its parent got killed? Is this behavior will different on different OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no one provides answer. So looks like it's not possible to implement it via the standard process model, but I solved it via running the separate daemon (background service) which is triggered by the main process, kill it and replaces with the new updated version and making it up and running again.